# from reference cells on another sheet using vba creating hyperlinks at last used cell on the sheet from reference cells on another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, hyperlink

What should be used if you want to create hyperlinks at the last full cell of column B on sheet2 with cells D1 and C1 of sheet1?

In the same sheet to create a hyperlink from cells one contains the link and the other the name to display, for example:

`ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Formula = "=hyperlink(D1,C1)"`

VBA code can be used. In this case you create hyperlink at cell A1 on sheet1, your D1 and C1 cells are also on sheet1.

I tried changing active worksheet to sheet2. changing range (a1) to `Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)` to select the last used cell on sheet 2.

Answer (score 0):

This is my question and i have found a solution after trying little bite. For anybody looking for an answer for such an situation mentioned above the solution is:

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(0).Formula = "=hyperlink(Sheet2!D1,Sheet2!C1)"

if you want to create the link below the last cell containing a value:

Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Formula = "=hyperlink(Sheet2!D1,Sheet2!C1)"

(Here, cell D1 of worksheet Sheet2 contains link adress to a folder on hard drive and cell D2 of worksheet Sheet2 contains the friendly name (text you want to be displayed instead of the link)

You can change the column letter .Range("A" to which column you want to create the link under. For instance if you want to create the link under the last value containing cell of column Z than change it to .Range("Z"

Hope it helps someone and saves time.